# how to split by period in clojure

Tags: java, clojure

```
> (clojure.string/split "clojure.org" #"\\.")

["clojure.org"]
```

I have read src of `split` which is

```
(defn split
  "Splits string on a regular expression.  Optional argument limit is
  the maximum number of splits. Not lazy. Returns vector of the splits."
  {:added "1.2"}
  ([^CharSequence s ^Pattern re]
     (LazilyPersistentVector/createOwning (.split re s)))
  ([ ^CharSequence s ^Pattern re limit]
     (LazilyPersistentVector/createOwning (.split re s limit))))
```

It calls `Pattern.split` inside. The strange thing is following codes work while Clojure doesn't

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.split("clojure.org")));

# output
[clojure, org]
```

Did I missing something?

Comment: (clojure.string/split "clojure.org" #"\.")   (single backslash to escape the '.' works for me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");
```

In Java, `"\\."` is a normal string. So you have to escape backslash itself in order to represent `\` in the regular expression.

```
user=> (clojure.string/split "clojure.org" #"\.")
["clojure" "org"]
```

In Clojure, `#"\."` is regular expression. Backslashes in the pattern are treated as themselves (and do not need to be escaped with an additional backslash)

The following webpage will be helpful. (Find "regex patterns" in the page)

http://clojure.org/reference/reader